# Magento 2 - separate registration form to register into customer group with custom field

Tags: magento2, registration

I want to add a separate registration form in Magento 2 store with the users directly go into a particular Customer Group and also I want to show up some custom fields too.

**More explanation:**

I have a customer group "dealer" and I want to create a separate user registration form when the user's register, there directly go into the "dealer" group, and also I want to show some custom fields too (these fields should not show up on the default registration form of the M2 store)

What I did is:

The registration form is coming from
`/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml`

So I duplicated that to

`/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Customer/templates/form/dealerregister.phtml`

And tried calling this form into CMS page by
`{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" template="Magento_customer::dealerregister.phtml"}}` but not gettnig anyouput on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" template="Magento_Customer::form/dealerregister.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
How to add custom form elements to this dealearregister.html?
I want to make the user to directly register into "Dealer" course group,  how to do that?

Comment: You can not set customer group through registration form as it is restricted. So you need to use event "customer_register_success" and update the customer group. By the way, you should create a module for this and should not use cms page for registration form.